# Segmentation and Abort Trap error in MPI app

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to parallelize some serial code which computes Mandelbrot set using OpenMPI. As the first step, I am trying to divide the work between different processes like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mpi.h"

// Main program
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    /* screen ( integer) coordinate */
    int iX,iY,i,j;
    const int iXmax = 5; // default
    const int iYmax = 5; // default

    /* world ( double) coordinate = parameter plane*/
    double Cx, Cy;
    const double CxMin = -2.5;
    const double CxMax = 1.5;
    const double CyMin = -2.0;
    const double CyMax = 2.0; 

    /* */
    double PixelWidth = (CxMax - CxMin)/iXmax;
    double PixelHeight = (CyMax - CyMin)/iYmax;


    int linePerProcess, remainingLines, processMinY,  processMaxY, lastProcessMaxY, result_offset;
    int my_rank, processors;
    unsigned char (*resultBuffer)[3] = NULL;
    unsigned char (*resultBufferTwo)[3] = NULL;
    unsigned char (*finalResultBuffer)[3] = NULL;
    MPI_Status stat;


    /* color component ( R or G or B) is coded from 0 to 255 */
    /* it is 24 bit color RGB file */
    const int MaxColorComponentValue = 255; 


    // RGB color array
    unsigned char color[3];

    /* Z = Zx + Zy*i;   Z0 = 0 */
    double Zx, Zy;
    double Zx2, Zy2; /* Zx2 = Zx*Zx;  Zy2 = Zy*Zy  */
    /*  */
    int Iteration;
    const int IterationMax = 1000; // default

    /* bail-out value , radius of circle ;  */
    const double EscapeRadius = 400;
    double ER2 = EscapeRadius * EscapeRadius;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processors);

    linePerProcess = iYmax / processors;
    remainingLines = iYmax % processors;
    processMinY = my_rank * linePerProcess;
    processMaxY = processMinY + linePerProcess;
    lastProcessMaxY = processMaxY + remainingLines;


    if (my_rank == 0) {

        finalResultBuffer = malloc(iXmax * iYmax * sizeof(color));

        for(iY = processMinY; iY < processMaxY; iY++) {

            Cy = CyMin + (iY * PixelHeight);
            if (fabs(Cy) < (PixelHeight / 2))
            {
                Cy = 0.0; /* Main antenna */
            }

            for(iX = 0; iX < iXmax; iX++)
            {

                Cx = CxMin + (iX * PixelWidth);
                /* initial value of orbit = critical point Z= 0 */
                Zx = 0.0;
                Zy = 0.0;
                Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                Zy2 = Zy * Zy;

            /* */
                for(Iteration = 0; Iteration < IterationMax && ((Zx2 + Zy2) < ER2); Iteration++)
                {
                    Zy = (2 * Zx * Zy) + Cy;
                    Zx = Zx2 - Zy2 + Cx;
                    Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                    Zy2 = Zy * Zy;
                };

            /* compute  pixel color (24 bit = 3 bytes) */
                if (Iteration == IterationMax)
                {
                    // Point within the set. Mark it as black
                    color[0] = 0;
                    color[1] = 0;
                    color[2] = 0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Point outside the set. Mark it as white
                    double c = 3*log((double)Iteration)/log((double)(IterationMax) - 1.0);
                    if (c < 1)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 0;
                        color[2] = 255*c;
                    }
                    else if (c < 2)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 255*(c-1);
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        color[0] = 255*(c-2);
                        color[1] = 255;
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                }

                finalResultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][0] = color[0];
                finalResultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][1] = color[1];
                finalResultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][2] = color[2];


            }
        }
        free(finalResultBuffer);


    } else if (my_rank == processors - 1) {

        resultBuffer = malloc((linePerProcess + remainingLines) * iXmax * sizeof(color));

        for(iY = processMinY; iY < lastProcessMaxY; iY++) {

            Cy = CyMin + (iY * PixelHeight);
            if (fabs(Cy) < (PixelHeight / 2))
            {
                Cy = 0.0; /* Main antenna */
            }
            for(iX = 0; iX < iXmax; iX++)
            {

                Cx = CxMin + (iX * PixelWidth);
                /* initial value of orbit = critical point Z= 0 */
                Zx = 0.0;
                Zy = 0.0;
                Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                Zy2 = Zy * Zy;

            /* */
                for(Iteration = 0; Iteration < IterationMax && ((Zx2 + Zy2) < ER2); Iteration++)
                {
                    Zy = (2 * Zx * Zy) + Cy;
                    Zx = Zx2 - Zy2 + Cx;
                    Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                    Zy2 = Zy * Zy;
                };

            /* compute  pixel color (24 bit = 3 bytes) */
                if (Iteration == IterationMax)
                {
                    // Point within the set. Mark it as black
                    color[0] = 0;
                    color[1] = 0;
                    color[2] = 0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Point outside the set. Mark it as white
                    double c = 3*log((double)Iteration)/log((double)(IterationMax) - 1.0);
                    if (c < 1)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 0;
                        color[2] = 255*c;
                    }
                    else if (c < 2)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 255*(c-1);
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        color[0] = 255*(c-2);
                        color[1] = 255;
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                }
                resultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][0] = color[0];
                resultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][1] = color[1];
                resultBuffer[(iY*iXmax)+iX][2] = color[2];


            }
        }
        free(resultBuffer);

    } else {

        resultBufferTwo = malloc(linePerProcess * iXmax * sizeof(color));

        for(iY = processMinY; iY < processMaxY; iY++) {
            Cy = CyMin + (iY * PixelHeight);
            if (fabs(Cy) < (PixelHeight / 2))
            {
                Cy = 0.0; /* Main antenna */
            }
            for(iX = 0; iX < iXmax; iX++)
            {

                Cx = CxMin + (iX * PixelWidth);
                /* initial value of orbit = critical point Z= 0 */
                Zx = 0.0;
                Zy = 0.0;
                Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                Zy2 = Zy * Zy;

            /* */
                for(Iteration = 0; Iteration < IterationMax && ((Zx2 + Zy2) < ER2); Iteration++)
                {
                    Zy = (2 * Zx * Zy) + Cy;
                    Zx = Zx2 - Zy2 + Cx;
                    Zx2 = Zx * Zx;
                    Zy2 = Zy * Zy;
                };

            /* compute  pixel color (24 bit = 3 bytes) */
                if (Iteration == IterationMax)
                {
                    // Point within the set. Mark it as black
                    color[0] = 0;
                    color[1] = 0;
                    color[2] = 0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Point outside the set. Mark it as white
                    double c = 3*log((double)Iteration)/log((double)(IterationMax) - 1.0);
                    if (c < 1)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 0;
                        color[2] = 255*c;
                    }
                    else if (c < 2)
                    {
                        color[0] = 0;
                        color[1] = 255*(c-1);
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        color[0] = 255*(c-2);
                        color[1] = 255;
                        color[2] = 255;
                    }
                }

                resultBufferTwo[(iY*iXmax)+iX][0] = color[0];
                resultBufferTwo[(iY*iXmax)+iX][1] = color[1];
                resultBufferTwo[(iY*iXmax)+iX][2] = color[2];

            }
        }
        free(resultBufferTwo);

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run this, I get segmentation error (11) as well as Abort trap (6) which only happens for processes ranked 1 and above. There is no problem in process 0. Can anyone help me understand the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexing into the result buffers is wrong for ranks above 0.

The buffers always start at index 0, regardless of which rank the code is running on. However, for ranks above 0, you start indexing at `processMinY * iXmax` instead. This then overwrites arbitrary memory, which can cause a segfault.

To fix this, you should subtract `processMinY` from `iY` when calculating the index into the buffer, e.g. `resultBufferTwo[((iY-processMinY)*iXmax)+iX][0] = color[0];`.

I also suggest you unify as much of the code for the different ranks as possible. Right now, most of your code is duplicated, even though the only lines that are actually different are the `malloc` calls and writing to the buffers. This makes the code hard to follow. You should create a variable for the size passed to `malloc`, and for the buffer, which you would then use in the loop. This way only the initialization of those two variables needs to differ between the ranks.